# Add a magic "question sandbox" tag for question sandboxes on per-site metas

Tags: feature-request, tags, per-site-meta, sandbox

The trend of having a question "sandbox" on a per-site meta so that users new to the site (or not) can post a draft of their intended question as an answer, and have it reviewed by site regulars before they go on to actually post the question on the main site, has gained a lot of traction on many sites. On Interpersonal Skills' version (don't know about other sites), people posting to the sandbox are expected to indicate the intended title and tags of their question as part of their sandbox submission. I only figured this out because there was an existing answer that contained them; if it wasn't there, I wouldn't have known. (The site requires that sandbox drafts which go on to be posted as questions be deleted.)

I propose that we add a new moderator-only tag [question-sandbox](/questions/tagged/question-sandbox), which would indicate that the question is one set aside specifically for that purpose, which would prefill the answer form with a template that can be useful for prompting users to add in the required title and tags, and create a unified and consistent theme for the submissions, such as:

```
### [draft title]

**tags:** [tag:tag1], [tag:tag2], [add more if needed]

---

[Your draft question body here]
```

We already have a tag with similar functionality, [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads), which prefills the answer form with the template for posting Community Promotion Ads.

This is also a first step towards allowing users without the necessary 5 rep to use the sandbox, as the system can use the presence of this tag to allow users without the required privileges to answer it. (The system is already coded to be aware of posts from <5 rep users on per-site metas, such as questions from users asking about their own posts, SO for Teams users on Meta.SO, users who've had their question migrated to a meta site, etc.)

Comment: What about other types of sandboxes? WorldBuilding also has an answer sandbox (that's hardly used), and several sites have formatting sandboxes. Should these also be given a/the special tag?

Comment: @Laurel If you're interested in those, you should file separate requests. This request is specifically about question sandboxes.